# Unable to amend glyphicon classes on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle `glyphicon-plus` with `glyphicon-minus` on each button click using `this` reference. You can see it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQPGL0FI65UR).

```js
$("#button-list button").each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-default btn-success");
    $(this + " span").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="button-list">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    1
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    2
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    3
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're attempting to concatenate `this`, which is a reference to the Element object that raised the event, to a string. This is not a valid selector.

Instead, you need to use the `find()` method to retrieve the `span` within `this` before changing the classes.

Also note that you don't need the `each()` loop. You can apply the `click` event handler to a collection of elements and jQuery will automatically handle it for you.

```js
$("#button-list button").on("click", function() {
  $(this)
    .toggleClass("btn-default btn-success")
    .find('span').toggleClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-list">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    1
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    2
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    3
  </button>
</div>
```